# How to find what state ManualResetEvent is in?

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking

I am using an instance of `ManualResetEvent` to control thread access to a resource but I'm running into problems with it.  Does anyone know how I can find out during debugging what the state of the object is?

That is to say I would like to know if the `ManualResetEvent` is currently blocking any threads and maybe even how many and which threads it is blocking.

Comment: Just for the record, on .NET 4 one can now use `ManualResetEventSlim`, which, among other things, provides an `IsSet` method that is [said to be](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/PerformanceCharacteristicsOfSyncPrimitives.pdf) faster than `WaitOne(0)`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Perform a `WaitOne` on the event with a timeout value of zero.

It will return true if the event is set, or false if the timeout occurs.
In other words, true -> event is set, false -> event is not set.

Comment: Thats a good idea, the debugger allows me to check its internals though, can't I find the state somewhere in there?

Comment: Hmm... Dunno. I seem to recall that it's an opaque object and not much help to look at.
However, you can probably execute the WaitOne call in the Immediate Window during debugging :)

Comment: You cannot check the internals because this class is a wrapper around an OS construct that is represented only by a handle.

Comment: What to do when WaitOne evaluation fails with "Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized." (on chk build!)

Comment: Store the return value in a variable and/or use System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write and set the breakpoint just after?

Answer (score 8):

Here is working code:

```
private ManualResetEvent pause = new ManualResetEvent(false);
pause.WaitOne(); // caller thread pauses
pause.Set();    // another thread releases paused thread

// Check pause state
public bool IsPaused { get { return !pause.WaitOne(0); } }
```

Comment: At least call it `IsBlocking`. I don't see how this enhances the given answer, I guess we can write down `WaitOne(0)` itself given the answer "Perform a `WaitOne` on the event with a timeout value of zero."

Answer (score 1):

You can make function calls in the Debugger Watch window.
Add a call to `mreVariable.WaitOne(0)` in the Watch window and see what it evaluates to.
Note: You should not use this for AutoResetEvents since that could change the actual state.